Was Willy Wonka correct when he accused Charlie of stealing Fizzy Lifting Drinks?
In the 1971 movie Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory, Willy Wonka says Charlie stole Fizzy Lifting Drinks. But was it really stealing? Admittedly, Mr. Wonka did not offer it to them but he also didn't prohibit them either.
He was very generous with all other aspects during the tour and offered many other things not released to the public, including an 'everlasting gobstopper'. And he never told them not to do most things, he just allowed them to endure the consequences.
Isn't it safe to assume that, without specific direction not to drink them, that Charlie and his grandfather would have accepted this as a tacit permission to do so?

Wonka explicitly forbids them, not once, but twice. He's also  uncharacteristically clear about his objections and the reasons for his objections.

Wonka: Bubbles, bubbles, everywhere, but not a drop to drink. Yet

And

Veruca: "Let us try some, please!"
Wonka: No, no, no. Absolutely not. There'd be children floating around all over the place.


The scene doesn't appear in the book (they don't enter the FIZZY LIFTING DRINKS room), but the 1971 screenplay is almost word-for-word for what we see in the film, so this wasn't an adlib or anything.

MR. WONKA: Fizzy-lifting-Drinks. They fill you with bubbles of gas and the gas is so terrifically lifting, it lifts you right off the ground like a balloon. Go for miles. But I daren't sell it yet! Still too powerful! There'd be children floating around all over the place.
Others: Let us try it! / Oh, let us / Oh, can't we?
MR. WONKA: Absolutely not! Come along, please! Don't hang about! (he starts to sweep everyone out of the door





Admittedly, leaving a group of visitors unmonitored in your food prep area is a terrible idea.

My memory of the final scene was that he wasn't so much accusing Charlie of stealing as simply having transgressed the rules (although, of course, there was the opportunity for him to "steal" the gobstopper and give it to Slugworth, which he resisted).

In the novel there's no drama to this moment at all. Wonka talks about the drink, and quickly explains that burping is how you stop floating.

@Valorum Wonka may have done it intentionally as a test (kind of like the marshmallow test). This whole contest was essentially a test to find his successor.

@Barmar - Of course it was a test. His people were observing the entire time

Valorum's answer correctly explains that Wonka did forbid Charlie from drinking the Fizzy Lifting Drink, so I'd instead like to focus on the "but was it really stealing?" aspect of the question. After all, Wonka didn't accuse Violet of "stealing" the three-course-meal chewing gum, even though he explicitly forbade the kids from trying it just as he forbade them from having the Fizzy Lifting Drink.
So why the harsher tone with Charlie? Because it was all part of Wonka's final test. He wanted to provoke Charlie, to see how he would react - whether he would try and get back at Wonka by selling the Everlasting Gobstopper to Slugworth, or do the right thing and give it back. The Fizzy Lifting Drink incident gave Wonka the perfect ammunition.
Wonka could have said something like "You defied my instructions", or "You drank something I told you not to drink", and it might have been a slightly more accurate description of events. Saying "You stole Fizzy Lifting Drinks" instead was a calculated effort to provoke Charlie that little bit more by painting him as a criminal. Charlie quietly surrendering the Everlasting Gobstopper instead of retaliating is what finally wins him the grand prize.

Indeed. Charlie was the only one who reached the end of the tour - had that been Violet instead of Charlie, he may well have been just as angry with her for "stealing" the chewing gum.

FWIW, the original Dahl book does not end like this. Charlie wins solely by virtue of not having broken any of the rules like the others (who are suffering from the effects of their decisions as they claim their lifetime supply of chocolate). This scene and the fizzy lifting drinks addition changes the tone of the story, necessitating this strangely tense scene with Wonka, who practically reads him the riot act to deny him any prize.

I would argue that the very fact that Grandpa Joe waited until everyone else had left, and then specifically says "no one is watching", is a clear indication to the audience that he knows he is suggesting something illicit.
As for whether it constitutes "stealing", I am hard-pressed to find any justification that it isn't. Setting aside that Wonka specifically says "no", stealing is taking something, that belongs to another, without their permission - Grandpa Joe and Charlie didn't own the item, they did not have explicit permission to take any amount of the item, and they permanently deprived the owner of an amount of the item. If the fizzy lifting drink were instead a jar full of gold coins, and the visitors each took one coin, without the owners permission, we would not hesitate to consider that as theft. Morally, I can't see any angle that would justify their behaviour as anything other than stealing, factor in Wonka's refusal to allow his guests to try it, and their surreptitious behaviour in taking it, it seems incredibly straight-forward, to my mind.
I hope this all makes some sense!

This is a great answer with one small nitpick. Depending on the size of the coins, the jurisdiction, and the fluctuating value of gold, there is a very good chance that stealing a single gold coin is grand larceny rather than petit larceny or petty theft. You may want to just remove the word "petty" to improve the answer.

Good point, well made! Thank you for the constructive feedback, much appreciated.

If I invite you around to my house, and I'm very generous with the nibbles and dips, and bottles of wine, etc. that doesn't mean I have implicitly given you permission to rifle through my fridge and down my last bottle of Curaçao.
One could even (quite reasonably imo) go as far as saying that it is especially bad behaviour, as it taking advantage of his generosity and general amicability by violating his personal boundaries and helping themselves to his things.
